# Where to find Santa’s secret hideaway?

Tags: achievements, post-apocalyptic-mayhem

I am trying to understand how to do the "Find Santa’s secret hideaway" achievement, in Post Apocalyptic Mayhem. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this thread](http://steamcheeves.com/):

> Start the winter map. It's easiest to turn around and keep driving
>   until you see a raised platform with a house on the right side. Drive
>   past it and turn around. Now boost into the left side of the house.

This video might also be helpful.